# postgresql backup file permissions

Tags: postgresql

Fellow admins, I'd like to ask you for advice.

Having a pgsql server (9.6 on Linux) the client intends to do incremental backup (keep the WAL files) for case of a disaster recovery.

Creating the WAL log files looks straightforward:

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /mnt/backups/%f && gzip < %p > /mnt/backups/%f'
```

The issue I have is related to two constraints:

- the solution is hosted and we don't want to give the client the root access
- the WAL files created are having permission 0600 (only the postgres user could read them)

Is there a way to let output the backup files with less restrictive permissions (like 0640 or 0644)?

The backup folder seems to have 0755 permission.

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cron job to copy the files to a folder the client can retrieve them from using SFTP.

Comment: I did not like the cron job idea, but maybe it may be reasonable at least to change the permissions (chmod) so the client could fetch (rsync) them. Looks viable too :)

Comment: As long as you're never going to put anything in that directory other than backup files for that specific client, sure.

Optionally, if THEY have an SFTP server, you could push the files to them with no need for a directory change.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I'd like to rsync WAL files to another machine. Here is what I end up doing:

1. Add postgres to the same group where WAL destination dir has (this could be the group client user is in).

```
    usermod -a -G clientgroup postgres
```

2. Change group and permissions in archieve_command

```
    archive_command = 'test ! -f /mnt/backups/%f.gz && gzip < %p > /mnt/backups/%f.gz && chgrp clientgroup /mnt/backups/%f.gz && chmod 640 /mnt/backups/%f.gz'
```

I'm not a security expert so I'd be happy to know if it's safe to do it this way.