# Having trouble implementing incremental backups (wal archiving) in a postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, backup, wal

I am using a postgres image and I would like to implement incremental backups. I have mounted a backup directory from my host machine to a backup dir in the container where postgres would supossedly archive the WAL files.

The archive_command in my config looks like this:

```
archive_command ='DIR="/var/backups/$(date +%Y%m%d)-wal"; (test -d "$DIR" || mkdir -p "$DIR") && gzip < "%p" > "$DIR/%f.gz"'
```

I've realized that the postgres user does not have the necessary permissions to write into /var/backups, and I believe every directory where it has permission to write is being used for something.

Any ideas on what I can do? Of course running a command like chown postgres /var/backups would simply rewrite the command of the original image, and I would like to use the base postgres image if possible. Isn't there any directory where postgres user can write to for these specific cases?

Comment: Hey! I think this question's answers may help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407164/postgresql-backup-file-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat solved it? I just added a script doing a chmod postgres /var/backups into the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder of the docker postgres container. Every script you put in that folder will be run when starting a container, so I just mounted a folder with the script from my host machine into that one.

It works but I don't know if it's the best practice.